# Difference between the multiple cash withdrawal options on these ATMs?

Tags: banking, bank-account, withdrawal, atm

I always get confused when selecting the options. I just go for the normal cash withdrawal option. But, I would like to know the difference in them. And, is the bank charging you different to use the different options?

[image: ICICI Bank ATM screen shot showing "Ultra Fast Cash", "Fast Cash", and "Cash Withdrawal" options]
[image: SILKBANK ATM screen shot showing "Fast Cash" and "Cash Withdrawal" options]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click the "fast cash" you will see [options](http://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/insta-banking/atm-banking/atm-banking.html) to withdraw

- Cash withdrawal option of prefixed amount

and "Ultra Fast Cash gives you the option:

- 'Ultra Fast Cash' - option to withdraw Rs. 3000/- in one shot

> And is the bank charging you different to use different options?

No ICICI Bank does not charge anything extra to use this option. It is just supposed to be for your convenience to withdraw money while your in a hurry. It saves you from making a few extra clicks.

Comment: +1 for the quick response! I was just not sure, and never tried the options in fear of losing extra money!
Now I guess I'll give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Ultra Fast Cash is Fixed amount of Rs 3000 with receipt.
Fast Cash is fixed amount to select typically Rs 1000; Rs 2000, Rs 4000, Rs 5000
Cash Withdrawl - Takes you through selection screens and you need to enter the amount.

HDFC Bank and other Banks allow you to set you amount. So next time you are withdrawing you can just hit that selection and not navigate.

Comment: Thank you dheer ,Your answer is the best and it helped me alot. +1

Answer (score 4):

I acknowledge the India tag, but I'd suggest that ATM menus are individual to each machine/bank, with common features around the world.

UltraFast - would pull a fixed amount from the main account - fixed sum that may be an option for the user to set for future visits.

Fast - would pull a choice of 3 fixed amounts from the main account.

(My ATM card ties to both my individual account and a joint account with my wife, the Joint account is considered 'main' at the ATM.)

Comment: +1 for the brief description! I tagged in India because I find these options in most of the banks there.. But, unless a normal user like me knows what the options are actually for, I'd refrain from choosing them...

Comment: @indrock - thank-you, and welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: well thank you! but i'm not new to Stack Exchange. I'm on [Drupal site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6461/indrock).. This is my first post here, this is a good site too, as most of the Stack Exchange sites :-)

Comment: Ha! Then welcome to Personal Finance & Money!

Comment: thank you! looking forward to gain some useful knowledge from here..